# Modem AT commands, unable to get into data mode (PPP)

Tags: iot, at-command, modem

I have a simcom7600 modem which I am trying out via AT commands.

I was able to use AT commands to setup the modem, and connect to an MQTT broker and exchange messages. Now I am trying to figure out how I can do something similar, but then with my own TCP/IP stack. Before diving into the deep there, I would like to confirm that I can get into data mode (PPP) which I am not able to, it seems.

I attached my modem (`AT+CGATT=1`), and activated it (`AT+ACACT=1,1`). I verified that I have a carrier/provider (`AT+COPS?`).

So I thought I was all set to send the `ATO` (online) commands. But it returns `NO_CARRIER` every time I try. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

The logging that confirms above statements:

```
AT+COPS?
Sending command: AT+COPS?
AT+COPS?[CR][CR][LF]+COPS: 0,0,"NL KPN simyo",7[CR][LF][CR][LF]OK[CR][LF]
AT+cgatt?
Sending command: AT+cgatt?
AT+cgatt?[CR][CR][LF]+CGATT: 1[CR][LF][CR][LF]OK[CR][LF]
AT+cgact?
Sending command: AT+cgact?
AT+cgact?[CR][CR][LF]+CGACT: 1,1[CR][LF]+CGACT: 2,0[CR][LF]+CGACT: 3,0[CR][LF][CR][LF]OK[CR][LF]
ATO
Sending command: ATO
ATO[CR][CR][LF]NO CARRIER[CR][LF]
```

PS: the [CR][LF] stand for resp. `\r` and `\n`, I replace them before I log for ease of reading.

I obviously have to supply more info to the modem, but from [this manual](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:SIM7500_SIM7600_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.08.pdf) I can't seem to figure out which commands I miss, and how I could validate step by step that I am on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this nice](https://www.cika.com/soporte/Information/GSMmodules/Quectel/AppNotes/Quectel_GSM_PPP_Application_Note.pdf) document. I'll share it here in case somebody else struggles with this as well.

When I send the following commands:

- `ATZ` (reset)
- `ATE0` (disable echo)
- `AT+CGREG?` (check registration to PDP network)
- `AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"` (set APN for my provider, they expect the string "internet")
- `ATD*99#` (start data mode, aka PPP)

then I can break out and move back into PPP with the following commands:

- `+++` (send + character, wait for 700ms, send + character, wait for 700ms, send + character) => back to AT command mode
- `ATO` (back to data mode)

**NOTE:** the APN your provider expects, is I think in all cases an easy Google. Your provider will most likely explain how to manually set your APN in case your phone won't do it automatically.

Comment: Your answer is correct, as it is basically the canonic way to start a PPP data connection. Just a note about `ATO`: it is basically a command to restore an active connection; in your case it didn't work because there wasn't any connection to restore. ;)

Comment: A further clarification: PPP is useful if you want to use the modem as a network adapter to convey data coming from your TCP/IP stack (for example coming from your PC o from an host processor with Linux, as an example). But almost all cellular modems, nowadays, support their own TCP stack and have a specific AT command suite managing sockets on that stack.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni thank you so much for you reply! I am really struggling figuring out which path I should follow. You mention the topics exactly which I am uncertain about. Should I bother with going ppp or should I just use the tcp stack on the modem? I figured, that when I go in ppp, and hook up lwip (which I am struggling with right now), I would be able to use my ppp connection for mutliple tasks at the same time. E.g. download stuff over FTP, and publish messages over mqtt. Where in the case of using the tcp stack on the modem, I would not be able to download and stay responsive on mqtt

Comment: at the same time. Would you have knowledge on that too? Does my concerns make any sense of can I use FTP and mqtt simultaneously using the modem as well? And maybe, even more important, if you have the answers to these questions, how did you learn this part? Could you point me to some documentation that explains this? Or is there a book you would suggest me to read maybe?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on your architecture (modem+PC? external ARM+modem?) and on what you have "ready". Take into account that most modems support also layer5 services such FTP (I see a lot of FTP commands in the guide) and that they usually support N sockets at the same time. Also, sometimes they support asynchronous request: you send the command and you read data as soon it arrives (search for "unsolicited messages" aka URCs). PS: I learnt this... after working for a cellular modem Vendor for 14 ys.. :)

Comment: Haha great I was afraid of that. Hard to soak 14ys exp in a week :). I am writing my sw on an stm32, so it's quite 'powerful' I guess. But you mentioned some interesting keywords again. I will dive into the manual of my modem again and play around with it a bit more. I guess more homework before I can really choose a direction.